# Excel 2016 Trying to get unique values from duplicate matches

Tags: excel, indexing, duplicates, aggregate, unique

I am currently running into an issue and need some help. I am using excel 2016, and in my current dataset (see sample) I am using an aggregate function to find my lowest 6 values and then I am trying to find the ID numbers of the vendors from these matches.

I tried using Index+Match, Index+Agg, and Index+match+Agg and they all failed. I am not sure how to loop through the table and find the id numbers based on just the sales reference number.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Excel sample data]

Comment: Suggest you use the `FILTER` function if you have it.

Comment: I do not appear to have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel 2016 you can use following formula for `ID`:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$7)/(B13=$C$2:$C$7),COUNTIF($B$13:B13,B13)))
```

for `Name` change first argument of `INDEX` function from `$A$1:$A$7` to `$B$1:$B$7`

[image]

Comment: First off...THANK YOU!!!, second I am not convinced this is not some Pirates of the Caribbean voodoo magic! 

Can you explain how this formula works please? I am so new to deep diving into excel and boolean algebra I am kind of at a loss of how you knew to use count if and / and all the other stuff/